# Symbology Stretch Multiple Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I need to change stretch of a raster using properties - Symbology to **Minimum-Maximum**
like image bellow :
 [image]

Problem is I have about 172 raster, is there any way to make this automaticaly change?
I have arcinfo license

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save you symbology in one layer, then use the tools "apply symbology for layer" (right click for batch).

Note also that you can define the default rendering for multispectral raster if you go to "customize > ArcMap option > raster > raster layer".

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution, but the gamma stretch also change refer to symbology we safe first, there are any ways to change the stretch type, but leaving Gamma Stretch Enable but untouched value?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by untouched value ? You can Enable a default Gamma stretch with your own values, but as it is default it will be applied to all images. If you want specific gamma stretch for different sets of images, then you need to use the lyr file (as suggested on top of my post)

Comment: all my raster have different gamma stretch, but it's ok I found the solution, I take 1 sample that have best gamma stretch and use your first method. Thank you.